# -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI dataUsingEncoding:] Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

My JSON string is

```
"{\"CommentList\":[{\"SubmittedDate\":\"02/01/2017 06:09:32\",\"SubmittedTime\":\"\",\"UserId\":\"af0e1cda5c0\",\"UserName\":\"NepolionBon\",\"Comments\":\"\",\"Complete_Hour\":\"\",\"Complete_Minute\":\"\"}]}"
```

I need value of "SubmittedDate" and "Complete_Hour" from it.

When I'm trying to convert this string with

```
NSData *responseData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

getting an error saying

```
 -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14decfc0
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure `responseString` is type of `NSString`?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: The error message clearly reveals that `responseString` is an `NSArray`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get `SubmittedDate` and `Complete_Hour`.

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"CommentList\":[{\"SubmittedDate\":\"02/01/2017 06:09:32\",\"SubmittedTime\":\"\",\"UserId\":\"af0e1cda5c0\",\"UserName\":\"NepolionBon\",\"Comments\":\"\",\"Complete_Hour\":\"\",\"Complete_Minute\":\"\"}]}";

    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray* arrComments = [json objectForKey:@"CommentList"];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in arrComments) {
        NSLog(@"Submit date :%@",[dict objectForKey:@"SubmittedDate"]);
        NSLog(@"Comlplete Hour : %@",[dict objectForKey:@"Complete_Hour"]);

    }
```

Comment: but i am getting error at NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Your `responseString` should be `NSString`.

Comment: Read Sunny's code again: Your code is probably trying to treat CommentList as a dictionary. But there are extra [ ] around it. Which means this is an array, containing one dictionary (in this case, at least). Your error says you are trying to call dataUsingEncoding on an NSArray (instead of an NSString).

That's what the for loop here does. So either you don't have this for loop, or you mixed up one of the variables.

Comment: Or if you are calling dataUsingEncoding at the start to get an NSData object for NSJSONSerialization, then that means you already have an array of something and not a string. Can you post your whole code? Have you run your program in the debugger to look at what type jsonString really has?

Comment: what was problem.

Comment: my response string was in two brackets. like ("{\"CommentList\":...). thats why i was getting this error -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI dataUsingEncoding:]